# Why doesn't file search work in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

**WebStorm version: 2020.1**

I try to find usage in file. I used "Ctrl + F" and "Edit->Find->Find", but it doesn't work.

Also I disabled all plugins, but it didn't help.

Comment: Add more details about what exactly happened. Including your steps and the expected/actual result you get - screenshots/screencast and anything that can add more clarify.

Comment: When I press "Ctrl + F" or open "Edit->Find->Find" search input doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by updating WebStorm to version 2020.3.2.